# Get DOB from Int Value Like 31Year,3Month,30Days from SQL Query

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, date

I am trying to Get DOB from Define values in 3 different textbox using sql query

1)First Text box contain for Year e.g. : 30

2)Second Text box contain for Month e.g. : 03

3)Third Text box contain for Day e.g. : 30

So i want date from above values.
My work around as follow:

```
declare @Year int = 31,
@month int = 4,
@day int = 0

Declare @TempDate Datetime,@TempDayPart int,@TempYearPart int,@TempMonthPart int,@FinalDate datetime,@checkLeapYear int,@chkChkDay int

SET @TempDate =DATEADD(YEAR, -@Year,CONVERT(date, GETDATE(),103))

select @TempDate as yearcount

SET @TempDate = DATEADD(MONTH, -@month , @TempDate)

select @TempDate as monthcount

SET @TempDate = DATEADD(DAY, -@day, @TempDate)

select @TempDate as FinalDate
```

This function is working fine for mostly scenario, but it is not correct for month of feb, whose dob DAY is greater than today's DAY

Note: For checking use this link http://www.calculator.net/age-calculator.html

1)Problem Date: 17-02-1986[or use any greater date of from month of feb from today like today is 16th so you can take 17th to 28 or 29 for FEB Calculation]

Comment: That is non-standard SQL. Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: In MS SQL server you can use [DATEFROMPARTS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datefromparts-transact-sql).  DATEFROMPARTS ( year, month, day ) It works in MSSQ 2012 and higher.

Answer (score 0):

try reversing your *DATEADD* calculations in the following order:::

```
SET @TempDate =DATEADD(DAY, -@day,CONVERT(date, GETDATE(),103))

--select @TempDate as daycount

SET @TempDate = DATEADD(MONTH, -@month , @TempDate)

--select @TempDate as monthcount

SET @TempDate = DATEADD(YEAR, -@year, @TempDate)

select @TempDate as FinalDate
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be better to set DOB using the to_date function, converting the Year, Month, and Day integers into a Date variable.  It looks like you're trying to show how old someone is based on their DOB, so this method would also make it easier to do this by finding the difference between the two dates.